# Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ not closed. Is then $A \cap K$ not closed in $K$ with the relative topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ not closed. Is then $A \cap K$ not closed in $K$ where $K$ is compact for example, with the relative topology? I mean by definition of the relative topology $U \cap K$ is open in $K$ if $U$ is open in $X$, but then $A \cap K$ could be of the form $B \cap K$ for some other $ B \subset X$ closed or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Wut is $K$?....

Comment: It is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to read if you put all the suppositions before the proposition:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $K \subset X$ compact, and $A \subset X$ not closed.  Is $A\cap K$ not closed in $K$?

The answer is no.  Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $K = [0,1]$.  Let $A = \{1\} \cup (2,3)$.  Clearly $A$ is not closed.  But $A \cap K = \{1\}$, which is closed.

Basically, “not closed” isn't a very robust condition.  Intersecting a non-closed set with a compact one can shear off its non-closed component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the constructive criticism. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

Observe for instance that $K$ is always closed in $K$. 
But in many situations there are lots of not closed sets $A$ with $K\subseteq A$ and consequently $A\cap K=K$.